# Multiple instances of shared object and parallel execution of each instance

Tags: pthreads, shared-libraries, dlopen

I have shared object *sw_core.so*. I need to have multiple instances (separate memory alloc) of this ".so" in main program. From the main program, I will be invoking `display_context()` function defined in *sw_core.so*. All `display_context()` need to run in parallel. *sw_core.so* is thread safe (no memory dependency to my knowledge).

To solve the above problem,

1. `dlopen` is used to invoke *sw_core.so* with `RTLD_LAZY` to have multiple instances of ".so".
2. `pthread` is used to invoke `display_context()` by getting symbol from `dlsym()`
3. Number of threads tried is 2
4. Anything above 2 is resulting segfault.
5. When I invoke 2 threads, segfault is coming when the 2nd thread write `pthread_join()`.
6. Tried valgrind tool to check memory leakage, but is not showing any serious leakage.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you're trying to do by loading same library several times. Data segment of a shared library created in one copy once per process and initialized by whatever initial values specified in the library.

If calls use some data or state stored in library, at best case you would overwrite that.

Comment: Hi,  The library "sw_core.so" created by me  is actually a prototype version of a library from a third party. The actually library is going to used an ".so" going to run with an executable created by Synopsys VCS tools (EDA tool used for chip design verification). The library is going to act as host processor with a single call from the main executable. So I need to have multiple instances of this library running with the main executable, each of them having its own context. Since it is developed to act as host processor , it is not developed as a conventional library functions manner.

Comment: `dlmopen` provides this sort of isolation (see the answer I posted).

Answer (score 0):

Note: I work at Synopsys. If you do as well Priyan you may want to contact me internally.

Next, the Valgrind perspective.
Memory leaks are not likely to be the issue. I would recommend that you ensure the you have no `memcheck` issues first. `memcheck` is single threaded so problems should not be related to threads. After that you can use DRD or Helgrind to detect threading issues.

Lastly, I don't think you can open multiple different instances of a shared library. The man page ([here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)) says

> If the same shared object is loaded again with dlopen(), the same
>   object handle is returned.  The dynamic linker maintains reference
>   counts for object handles, so a dynamically loaded shared object is
>   not deallocated until dlclose() has been called on it as many times
>   as dlopen() has succeeded on it.  Any initialization returns (see
>   below) are called just once.  However, a subsequent dlopen() call
>   that loads the same shared object with RTLD_NOW may force symbol
>   resolution for a shared object earlier loaded with RTLD_LAZY.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I will contact you formally.

Comment: "The man page (here) says" - and it also says about `dlmopen` which does allow this (see the answer I posted).

Answer (score 0):

`Dlopen` probly does not work because it causes false sharing of public symbols between different versions of `sw_core.so`. To achieve proper isolation use [dlmopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html):

```
void *h = dlmopen (LM_ID_NEWLM, "path/to/sw_core.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for all your help ! I could successfully load single library multiple times,each one of them in separate namespace with dlmopen(). Only issue which I have faced is that gcc was not supporting dlmopen(). I checked till 4.9 version, but no success. With g++, no issues was seen in loading.

All static,global, static-global variables are having its own memory for each instances of the library loaded.

Note :- I am using a my own lib (argument to dlmopen) for this experiment not any standard libraries.

- Priyan